# SQL Server Project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013.

Most of my projects could be opened with VS2013 except for a SQL Server 2008 Database project (which is listed as incompatible).

VS2013 project templates doesn't include the SQL Server 2008 Database project so I'm wondering if those projects type are still suppose to be supported in VS 2013.

Comment: Is this Visual Studio Express 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Visual Studio 2013 Compatibility page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx) on MSDN,

#### For Visual Studio 2010 Database (.dbproj)

> If you convert the project to a SQL Server Data Tools Database
> project, you can open it in Visual Studio 2013. However, Visual Studio
> 2013 doesn’t support these artifacts: unit tests data-generation plans
> data-comparison files custom rule extensions for static code analysis
> server.sqlsettings .sqlcmd files custom deployment extensions partial
> projects (.files) If you install SQL Server Data Tools, you can open
> the project in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 after the conversion. For more
> information, see Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools.

It does not mention anything about your version -- Sql Server 2008.

Try installing the [SQL Server Data Tools - October 2013 Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015). Not sure if that will fix it though, because the [Sql Server Data Tools download page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) lists only Visual Studio 2010 and 2012.