# How can I create SQL Server Database Project In Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, new-project

I use SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2013.

I want to create a SQL Server Database Project but I can't find this type of project in my Visual Studio. I installed Update 4 in Visual Studio.

Should I install something in my Visual Studio?

[image]

In Visual Studio 2012 I have this menu:

[image]

Comment: Related (arguably duplicate): [SQL Server Project in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032321/sql-server-project-in-visual-studio-2013).

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I did not upgrate from 2010 to 2013

Comment: That's why I didn't VTC. But it talks about use of that project template in VS 2013.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I can create a new project with type of SQL Server Database Project

Comment: Take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/01/30/ssdt-and-visual-studio-versions.aspx

Comment: @MatthewHaugen : Tanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).

VS 2012:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

VS 2013:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: Are you sure? this link is for Visual studio 2012. "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 "

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi: Try this link then: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42313